# What is "platforms" for in manifest.json?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

In [manifest.json definition](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest), there is a "platforms" key.

However, I cannot find it documented anywhere. What does it do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `platforms` key in the manifest file is part of a feature called *multi-platform zip files*, which is only relevant for [NaCl](https://developer.chrome.com/native-client). Developers can reduce the size of the crx file by putting platform-specific files in the `_platform_specific` directory and listing the directories in the `platforms` key in `manifest.json`. Users who then install the CRX from the Chrome Web Store will then only get the files specific for their platform.

This feature is documented at https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/devguide/distributing#distributing-packaged.